# Matlab - fft form ascii

Tags: matlab, ascii

I want to represent a FFT based on measurements i have saved on a file.
The file is in the format [frequency, amplitude] i.e.

```
0,00;0,15;
3,91;0,34;
7,81;0,60;
11,72;1,66;
15,63;3,66;
19,53;0,98;
23,44;0,60;
27,34;0,44;
31,25;0,35;
35,16;0,29;  
39,06;0,25;
42,97;0,22;
46,88;0,20;
```

How can i plot those data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem when reading this from a file is that it uses commas instead of points to separate the decimals. To avoid any issues with this, you can read the content of the file as text (leading to one string variable) and replace the commas with points in MATLAB:

```
fileContent = fileread('input_file.txt'); 
fileContent = strrep(fileContent ,',','.');
```

Next you can use the `sscanf` (string scan) function to extract the floating point values (`%f`) from the string. With `[2,inf]` you specify you want the output to have two rows and as many columns as needed.

```
A = sscanf(fileContent ,'%f;%f;\n',[2,inf]);
```

You then have an array `A` with the frequencies in the first row and the corresponding values in the second row. With that you can create any plot you like, e.g.

```
stem(A(1,:),A(2,:));
title('FFT of a signal');
xlabel('Frequency (Hz)');
ylabel('Amplitude');
```

Comment: Your solution seems to work, tho im plotting the data and it returns a plot like [link]http://i.imgur.com/lWKu9bL.png?1 which does look weird. Im kinda thinking i should take average values to get a curve instead a bunch of points. But thats another thing i cant do in matlab :P Cheers.

Comment: It does look strange. Are there any strange entries (e.g. frequency=zero) at the end of the file (or better: matrix `A`)? Or is it possible that the data is repeated multiple times in the file? I.e. after frequency 500, it starts with 0 again and so on?

Comment: I have an entry of 0 freq with some amplitude but thats pretty much natural. It seems that the solution lies on ur second assumption, i got multiple entries. Tried with the first set 0-500 freq where 500hz respond to the nyquist frequency and it did the trick. But i'm thinking that FFT is not that accurate for one cycle than it would be for several ones.

Comment: Ok, nice. You can either try to use all samples you have in the time domain to calculate the FFT for one cycle, or you can read all FFTs you have in the file into MATLAB and calculate the average over these.